# ASP.NET Development Server with Basic Authentication

Tags: asp.net

Anyone aware of how to get the ASP.NET Dev Server to challenge for basic authentication credentials instead of assuming my current login?

Comment: I am not running in IIS guys.

Comment: what are you running in?

Comment: The ASP.NET Development Server AKA Casinni

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If using Cassini then according to paragraph at bottom of this link - [Limitations of the Cassini Web Server](http://www.west-wind.com/webconnection/docs/_2611d4rbh.htm), you cant.

If using IIS, then update IIS authentication.

In IIS,

- in the virtual directory of your site right click on your virtual directory,
- select the Directory Security tab
- select Edit button next to Anonymous access and authentication control
- uncheck allow anonymous and integrated windows authentication
- check basic authentication

Comment: Easy fix - switch to using IIS :D (It's a 'more accurate' reproduction anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question, per se, but consider configuring your web project's properties to "Don't open a page.  Wait for a request from an external application", and then hit your server with a browser that's been launched with alternative credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Integrated Windows authentication checked off under Directory Security in IIS, instead of (or in addition to) Basic?